# 4 hours report in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive table with columns -> `date, hr, count` where `date, hr` are partitions. I want to query the table for `4 hours summarized data` considering i have  data and time in hand.

Example -> If i have date as 2012-02-08 and hr as 02 then the summarized report should contain be summarized count of `2012-02-07,23|2012-02-08,00|2012-02-08,01|2012-02-08,02`

I would like to know is there a way to query in one shot.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do a group by where you group by date and hr:

```
select date, hr, count(1)
from table
group by date, hr
```

Also have has some extra date and time functions that might be useful like hour(datetime) or minute, day.